# How do I wrap the whole application in the new version of next.js?

Tags: next.js, recoiljs

I know how to wrap root directory in old version of next.js. But I don't know how to do this in the new version. I searched but couldn't find any examples.[_app.tsx example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8kkQ.png)

I tried something like but that didn't work, I think I'm doing it wrong.[layout.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOhoN.png)